# Does stdio set file descriptor offset back to next unread position on file closing?

Tags: c, fork, glibc, stdio

According to the Linux Programmer's Manual, after calling `fork`, parent and child processes share opened file descriptors and file offsets.

On the other hand, it is known, that glibc's stdio implements bufferisation. Therefore, call to `scanf` can result in moving file offset (reading) much further then number of bytes returned to the end user, remaining data will be stored in buffer for the next call.

But what happens when I do the following:

1. Call `fork`. Now parent and child share `stdin`.
2. In the child process call `scanf`. By default `stdin` is block buffered, so `scanf` reads block.
3. Inspect file offset in child.
4. Exit from the child process.
5. In parent process wait for the child process.
6. Inspect file offset of `stdin` in the parent.

According to the [glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Closing-Streams.html), when `main` returns,

> all opened streams are closed properly.

and on closing

> any buffered input is **discarded**

So I expect parent's `stdin` file offset to be at position where child's `scanf` stoped reading (really stoped reading). But I get parent's `stdin` file offset moved back to position of end of input returned to user.

I searched trough the manuals and the internet and didn't find any information describing this behavior. Is it specified?

Here is my code:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int fd = fileno(stdin);
    printf("Begin pos: %ld\n", lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR));
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        char buffer[4096] = {};
        int readed = scanf("%s", buffer);
        printf("Child readed: %d, pos: %ld\n", readed, lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR));
        return 0;
    }

    int status = 0;
    wait(&status);
    printf("Parent pos: %ld\n", lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR));

    return 0;
}
```

Here is output:

```sh
> echo "aaa bbb ccc" > test
> ./a.out < test
Begin pos: 0
Child readed: 1, pos: 12
Parent pos: 3
```

Comment: After a fork, the parent and child do not share stdin.  In each, stdin contains an underlying file descriptor which references the same file description, but the data structures are distinct.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, I understand this, but thank you for making it clear.

Comment: I suppose it is a pedantic point, but this seems to cause a lot of confusion for people.  I worry that my clarification may just obscure things further, though. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observed behavior conforms to the POSIX requirements for the [`fclose`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fclose.html) function:

> If the file is not already at EOF, and the file is one capable of seeking, the file offset of the underlying open file description shall be set to the file position of the stream if the stream is the active handle to the underlying file description.